# Customized Fisher exact test in R

Tags: r, statistics

*Beginner's question ahead!*
(after spending much time, could not find straightforward solution..)

After trying all relevant posts I can't seem to find the answer, perhaps because my question is quite basic.

I want to run fisher.test on my data (Whatever data, doesn't really matter to me - mine is Rubin's children TV workshop from QR33 - http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/qr33.pdf) It has to simulate completely randomized experiment.

My assumption is that RCT in this context means that all units have the same probability to be assigned to treatment(1/N). (of course, correct me if I'm wrong. thanks).

I was asked to create a customized function and my function has to include the following arguments:

1. Treatment observations (vector)
2. Control observations (vector)
3. A scalar representing the value, e.g., zero, of the sharp null hypothesis; and
4. The number of simulated experiments the function should run.

When digging in R's fisher.test I see that I can specify X,Y and many other params, but I'm unsure reg the following:

1. What's the meaning of Y? (i.e. `a factor object; ignored if x is a matrix.` is not informative as per the statistical meaning).
2. How to specify my null hypothesis? (i.e. if I don't want to use 0.) I see that `there is a class "htest" with null.value` but how can I use it in the function?
3. Reg number of simulations, my plan is to run everything through a loop - sounds expensive - any ideas how to better write it?

Thanks for helping - this is not an easy task I believe, hopefully will be useful for many people.

Cheers,

NB - *Following explanations were found unsatisfying:*

https://www.r-bloggers.com/contingency-tables-%E2%80%93-fisher%E2%80%99s-exact-test/

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252234/compute-a-fisher-exact-test-in-r

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133441/computing-the-power-of-fishers-exact-test-in-r

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147559/fisher-exact-test-on-paired-data

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me that a Fisher test is necessarily the right thing for what you're trying to do (that would be a good question for stats.SE) but I'll address the R questions.

1. As is explained at the start of the section on "Details", R offers *two* ways to specify your data.

   You can either 1. supply to the argument `x` a contingency table of counts (omitting anything for `y`), or you can supply observations on individuals as two vectors that indicate the row and column categories (it doesn't matter which is which); each vector containing factors for `x` and `y`. [I'm not sure why it also doesn't let you specify `x` as  a vector of counts and `y` as a data frame of factors, but it's easy enough to convert]
2. With a Fisher test, the null hypothesis under which (conditionally on the margins) the observation-categories become exchangeable is independence, but you can choose to make it one or two tailed (via the `alternative` argument)
3. I'm not sure I clearly understand the simulation aspect but I almost never use a loop for simulations (not for efficiency, but for clarity and brevity). The function `replicate` is very good for doing simulations. I use it roughly daily, sometimes many times.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b . Follow up:

(Best would be a code snippet to explain, if you could)

1. I was asked to provide function with the arguments mentioned, so contingency matrix as a dataframe would work here (i.e. X as a matrix).

2. for fisher exact test, the null is often no difference between means: (mean(Y0)-mean(Y1)=0). That's what I meant.
3. I also don't understand why it is necessary, hence this question.

Thanks again.

Comment: 1. I can't supply code for something when I can't fathom what you're trying to achieve; the questions about R were answerable ... and I'm probably not going to write all your code to spec for you even if I did understand it. Brief snippets or short functions - sure. 2. No, I'm sorry but you're mistaken. That's *never* the case. Ask about that one on stats.  This is probably why I couldn't understand what you were doing in your simulation.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b . I"ll provide the question as it was given - maybe that would help:
"
(1) Create a function in R that runs the Fisher Exact Test and produces empirical “p” values for a completely randomized experiment, with a test-statistic defined as the difference in treatment/control group means, given the following arguments: (i) a vector of observed outcomes for the treatment group; (ii) a vector of observed outcomes for the control group that is not necessarily the same size as the treatment group;"

Comment: (cont.)
" (iii) a scalar representing the value, e.g., zero, of the sharp null hypothesis; and (iv) the number of simulated experiments the function should run. Validate your code using published results from the Rubin’s Children’s Television Workshop example."

Comment: As the terminology is usually used [Fisher's Exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_exact_test) is not a test for means; it's *only* a test for independence. That's also what the R function does. I think what they actually want is a permutation test (which are sometimes called exact tests and were named and largely invented by Fisher -- but nevertheless the term "Fisher Exact test" is almost universally understood to be the specific test for contingency tables just as Wikipedia indicates -- the broader class of tests ***don't*** get the word "Fisher" on the front).

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Could you possibly help writing such a function? thanks. @Glen_b

Comment: Compare [permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests) vs [Exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_test) to see that "exact test"  is actually broader.

Comment: To repeat: I'm not going to do your assignment for you. Don't keep asking. If you have specific questions about the computing or the statistical side they might be answerable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137615/discussion-between-oba2311-and-glen-b).